# Privacy implications of storing and transmitting GPT-3 embeddings?

Tags: word-embedding, embeddings, gpt-3

We are exploring implementing a feature where a user might enter "which product has optional all wheel drive" into a search input, which would be transformed to GPT-3 embeddings, and compared against a set of embeddings for product descriptions to return similar products.

If a user enters PII and/or sensitive data, for example "my name is Jim, what will help with my COPD", then the embeddings that are generated will include this sensitive information.

Is it possible to reverse the embeddings GPT-3 creates back to the exact phrase entered?  If not, are there metrics like anonymity that can be used to reason about exactly how sensitive the embedding are?